# How to use `duration_cast` for a derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I'm cleaning up my timer class using `std::chrono`. Everything else went smooth except that I cannot seem to apply `duration_cast` to derived classes. Well, I made it work in a different way, but I'd still like to know what I missed.

See [here](http://ideone.com/TuVs4g) for the error message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

class Milliseconds : public std::chrono::milliseconds
{
public:
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds Base;
    typedef Base::rep Type;

    using Base::Base;
};

inline Milliseconds::Type millisecondsSinceEpoch()
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<Milliseconds::Base>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    //duration_cast<Milliseconds> ERROR!
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << millisecondsSinceEpoch() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen https://ideone.com/TuVs4g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `duration_cast` can only be used to convert to a specialization of `duration`. [time.duration.cast]/p1:

> ```
> template <class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>
> constexpr ToDuration duration_cast(const duration<Rep, Period>& d);
> ```
>
> *Remarks*: This function shall not participate in overload resolution unless `ToDuration` is an instantiation of `duration`.

If `ToDuration` is not a specialization of `duration`, then the signature is removed from overload resolution (by SFINAE or a similar technique), and the call fails unless another function template called `duration_cast` is available.

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ 2015 RC issues the following error when substituting `duration_cast<Milliseconds>` in your code:

```
error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'enable_if<std::chrono::_Is_duration<_Ty>::value,_To>::type std::chrono::duration_cast(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period> &)'
```

The `std::chrono::_Is_duration<_Ty>` trait is an internal implementation detail of the standard library used in MSVC; it's there to make things work according to the standard and make the error message easier to understand: you need to give `duration_cast` a template argument that really is a specialization of the `std::chrono::duration` template. Derived-to-base relationships are not considered in this case.

[20.12.5.7] in the standard (N4431 draft) has the following description:

```
template <class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>
  constexpr ToDuration duration_cast(const duration<Rep, Period>& d);
```

> *Remarks:* This function shall not participate in overload resolution unless `ToDuration` is an instantiation of `duration`.

---

Base class template specializations are considered when deducing template arguments from the types of the arguments of a function call [14.8.2.1], but not when matching arguments to class template partial specializations [14.5.5.1], which is what happens for the `_Is_duration` trait.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your own `duration_cast`.

```
template< typename my_dest, typename my_source >
my_dest duration_cast( my_source const & value )
    { return duration_cast< my_dest::duration >( value ); }
```

It's not allowed to put this in `namespace std::chrono`, so you can't call this as `std::chrono::duration_cast`. One alternative is to add `using std::chrono::duration_cast` and `using my_namespace::duration_cast` to your namespace, and qualify with calls with that instead. (In the example, you're not using a namespace, so only the `using std`… is needed.)

Comment: ADL is only going to find it if `value` is of a type from that namespace, which is not the case in the OP's example. Also, the call uses an explicit template parameter, so, in order to be parsed as a *template-id*, a declaration for a function template with that name needs to be available to normal unqualified lookup first, otherwise it's not going to get to the ADL phase.

Comment: @bogdan ADL also finds functions in namespaces associated with explicit template arguments. Yes, there does need to be a declaration available to unqualified lookup. A `using` declaration importing from either `std` or his own utility library is sufficient.

Comment: No, not in this case; not those in the template-id that is the postfix expression of the function call. If a *function argument* has a type that is a class template specialization, then ADL finds functions in namespaces associated with template arguments of that template specialization; and also in all kinds of other constructs, but all related to the types of the function arguments. [3.4.2p2]: *[...] The sets of namespaces and classes is determined entirely by the types of the function arguments (and the namespace of any template template argument). [...]*

Comment: @bogdan Check the very end of that paragraph: "Additionally, if the aforementioned set of overloaded functions is named with a template-id, its associated classes and namespaces also include those of its type template-arguments and its template template-arguments."

Comment: That *aforementioned set of overloaded functions* refers to the sentence immediately above: *In addition, if the argument is the name or address of a set of overloaded functions and/or function templates [...]*. It's still about function arguments, and not the name in the function call itself. Write a simple test, and you'll see that it doesn't work (I remember testing it on three different compilers a while ago).

Comment: @bogdan Ah, you're right. Actually that last sentence is an extremely obscure corner case http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/233f4a372285b72d which is implemented by GCC but not Clang.

Comment: Nice find on the Clang bug. I've just verified that MSVC 14 RC has the same problem. I'd say these should be reported. Do you want to do it yourself?

Comment: @bogdan Already did for Clang. https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23714 I'm not a MSVC user, so you can do that.

Comment: [Submitted on MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1389188).